# Couldn't find input index file %.idx - Texmaker - single column elsevier 2023 template

Tags: texmaker, nomenclature

I am writing a paper for elsevier journal, and I am using the new single column template (2023), I am trying to add the nomenclature to the paper, with the classical steps I have been done in the past:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex %

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textit{Symbols}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\item[\textit{Subscripts}]}{}
    }
}
%
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items
\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
```

and then:

```
\begin{table*}[!t]   
\begin{framed}

\nomenclature{\textit{V$_{c}$}}{Clearance volume}
\nomenclature{\textit{V$_{d}$}}{Displacement volume}

\printnomenclature
\end{framed}
\end{table*}
```

and it does not work.... I use the windows command prompt  with the classical command line:

"makeindex .nlo -s nomencl.ist -o .nls"

and then compile PDF, and them makeindex again and it does not work..

I get an error:

Couldn't find input index file "xxxxxxx" nor xxxxxxx.idx.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Can someone give me a help? please?

The elsevier 2023 single column template is at:

https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions

Thanks a lot!!

Leonel.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Please replace `\textit{V$_{c}$}` with `$V_c$` and `\textit{V$_{d}$}` with `$V_d$`.

Comment: Hello Mico, thanks, I did...  still not working...

Comment: Note that I prefaced my comment with "off-topic".

Comment: @Leonel The error seems straightforward, the file you're running `makeindex` on is not in the current working directory.  If latex is running successfully then nomenclature should be generating a `foo.nlo`, and `makeindex foo.nlo ...` should be giving a different error.  Is your latex compilation successful? Does it generate a `foo.nlo` auxiliary file? If it is there, does running `makeindex foo.nlo` from a terminal in the working directory still give the "Couldn't find input index file" error?